# innerHTML and console.log difference in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch API from my local Json. My console.log shows what I exactly want in `for loop`. But my `output.innerHTML` doesn't work. I tried firstly with my `<div></div>` tags and then I convert It  to `pre` tag. Still doesn't work.It just shows one line.What I am missing any idea ?

data.json :

```
"resultCode": "0",
    "resultDescription": "success",
    "body": {
        "intraDayTradeHistoryList": [
            {
                "id": 444121195,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:34.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012603",
                "price": 731.99,
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 444121022,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:35.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012603",
                "price": 732,
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 444121234,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:43.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012603",
                "price": 731.99,
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 444120877,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:56.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012608",
                "price": 1341.99,
                "quantity": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 444121289,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:56.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012608",
                "price": 1341.98,
                "quantity": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 444121519,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:57.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012608",
                "price": 1342,
                "quantity": 120
            },
            {
                "id": 444120887,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:58.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012608",
                "price": 1342.88,
                "quantity": 50
            },
            {
                "id": 444121529,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:00:59.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012608",
                "price": 1342.9,
                "quantity": 65
            },
            {
                "id": 444120892,
                "date": "2022-01-26T00:01:00.000+0300",
                "conract": "PH22012608",
                "price": 1343.8,
                "quantity": 100
            },
]};
```

index.html(omitted hard codes) :

```
<body>
    <pre id="output"><br></pre>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

main.js file :

```
const output = document.getElementById("output");

const jsonData = fetch("./data.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    //const dataLen = data.body.intraDayTradeHistoryList.length;
    const tradeHist = () => 
    {
    for(let i = 0; i <= 5;i++){
          output.innerHTML = (JSON.stringify(data.body.intraDayTradeHistoryList[i]));
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data.body.intraDayTradeHistoryList[i]));

    }
}
tradeHist();
})
.catch(error => console.log("Error"))
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting `innerHTML` 5 times? Presumably you meant to do `output.innerHTML += ...`? And even that would be a bad solution because it forces the browser to re-render 5 times. Instead, define a local variable `html`, initialized with an empty string and build that string in your loop, then after the loop assign it to `innerHTML`. Also defining that local function `tradeHist` seems useless.

Comment: You are overwriting the `innerHTML` each time, so only one result is being showed. You should use `+=` instead of `=` to add content.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I solved the problem. But why are you angry with me I don't know. I thought that this site for helpful? Am I wrong? I am just a student trying to figure out how things work. I researched before I asked. But these days I am dealing with a lot of homework and different programming languages. Whatever guys. Thanks again.

Comment: First of all, you are overriding your `output` content on each loop, is that intended? Other than that, when your stringify some json you can do it like this `JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)` in order to indent the content with 4 spaces

Comment: No one is angry with you, why do you think so?

Comment: @theplaceofburak - I'm sorry you see it that way, and sorry I missed that one bit of the question. I disagree that the comment was at all offensive, but we can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in my comment, here's the fixed code:

```js
const jsonData = fetch("./data.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(({body: {intraDayTradeHistoryList}}) => {
    let html = '';
    for (const entry of intraDayTradeHistoryList){
        html += JSON.stringify(entry);
    }
    output.innerHTML = html;
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```